# The cohomology ring of the nerve of a category associated to a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $n\ge2$, and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $k$.  Consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects are nonzero, proper subspaces of $V$, and whose morphisms are inclusions.  Let $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{C})$ be the nerve of $\mathcal{C}$, and $X:=|\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{C})|$ its geometric realization.  What is the cohomology ring $H^*(X,k)$?

I'm having trouble working this out even in the case $n=2$.  Any help or references would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: When $n = 2$ the only possible dimension of a nonzero proper subspace is $1$, so the category is discrete.

Comment: I also don't see any reason to take cohomology with the same coefficients as the field you started with.

Comment: Anyway, if you want references, try googling "poset homology" or "poset topology."

Comment: If you are talking about two dimensional real vector spaces, then the simplicial complex that you have is simply a discrete set of points, one for each line through the origin. However, if  you topologize this you get a circle (actually better thought as a double cover of the circle). So for finite fields, the answer is below. For real or complex fields, I think that one should also talk about the topology.

Comment: You mean one *might* talk about the topology, @BabyDragon :) The OP's question is clearly stated and in it the collection of subspaces is thought of as discrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplicial complex you describe is called the Tits building for $GL_n(k)$.  When $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ it is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $p^{n(n-1)/2}$ spheres of dimension $n-2$. I think that theorem is due to Quillen, and am pretty sure that volume II of Benson's *Representations and Cohomology* contains a proof. I don't know what happens for other fields.